# How can I show the netstat command in powershell without the 0 in the Local address?

Tags: powershell, netstat

I hope I could explain, sorry for my english

```
  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1160
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5040           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       8864
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5357           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7680           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       14052
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49664          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       964
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49665          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       872
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49666          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1696
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49667          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1448
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49668          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3380
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49710          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       944
```

but what i want

```
Local Address
135
445
5040
5357
7680
49664
49665
49666
49667
49668
49710
```

Also, how can I show this on the screen with what code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the string output is acceptable, then one of the easiest ways to achieve your desired result is to simply remove the unwanted string with `regex`. However it will mess up the formatting.

```
(netstat -ano) -replace '0\.0\.0\.0:'

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    135            0              LISTENING       868
  TCP    445            0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    5040           0              LISTENING       7288
  TCP    5357           0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    5985           0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    6783           0              LISTENING       5128
  TCP    47001          0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    49664          0              LISTENING       976
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6463         0              LISTENING       14660
  TCP    127.0.0.1:6800         0              LISTENING       7468
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8094         0              LISTENING       4348
```

This is a huge drawback from Powershell's object based output. You could try to correct the alignment manually if you so desire..

```
(netstat -ano) -replace '0\.0\.0\.0:(\d+)','$1        '

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    135                    0                      LISTENING       868
  TCP    445                    0                      LISTENING       4
  TCP    5040                   0                      LISTENING       7288
  TCP    5357                   0                      LISTENING       4
  TCP    5985                   0                      LISTENING       4
  TCP    6783                   0                      LISTENING       5128
  TCP    47001                  0                      LISTENING       4
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8094         0                      LISTENING       4348
  TCP    127.0.0.1:8763         0                      LISTENING       5128
  TCP    127.0.0.1:9527         0                      LISTENING       5128
  TCP    127.0.0.1:37014        0                      LISTENING       4576
```

Again, these examples really only benefit the user viewing it. If you want to use the data later on, you'd have to parse it. At this point you really should look at the powershell alternatives such as [Cpt.Whale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7411885/cpt-whale)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70175566/4085331) shows.

Comment: How can I show only the local address and the PID in addition to the code you wrote?

Comment: Sounds like you need to ask a other question. Does this answer your current question?

Comment: @Volkan https://pastebin.com/gVwW8Mtc

Answer (score 1):

`Get-NetTCPConnection` is the powershell-equivalent of `netstat`, and it helpfully separates out the port numbers you're looking for. For example, here's what it looks like normally:

```sql
Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalAddress 0.0.0.0 -State Listen

LocalAddress LocalPort RemoteAddress RemotePort State  AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------ --------- ------------- ---------- -----  -------------- -------------
0.0.0.0      58369     0.0.0.0       0          Listen                3892         
0.0.0.0      49677     0.0.0.0       0          Listen                792          
0.0.0.0      49672     0.0.0.0       0          Listen                3900
```

And then to display just the port numbers, you can add `Select-Object`:

```
Get-NetTCPConnection -State Listen | 
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty LocalPort

58369
49677
49672
```

edit: To filter by listening address, you can use the `-LocalAddress` parameter, or use `Where-Object`:

```sql
# Using LocalAddress
Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalAddress 0.0.0.0,127.0.*,192.168.* -State Listen

LocalAddress  LocalPort RemoteAddress RemotePort State  AppliedSetting OwningProcess
------------  --------- ------------- ---------- -----  -------------- -------------
127.0.0.1     62522     0.0.0.0       0          Listen                3432         
0.0.0.0       58369     0.0.0.0       0          Listen                3892         
127.0.0.1     50595     0.0.0.0       0          Listen                16596
```

Comment: thank you so much. Well, I'm giving an example, how can I show the ones that start with 127 and 192 at the same time, in addition to the code you wrote.

Comment: @Volkan I've added an example of what I think you are looking for. Be aware that if you don't use the `-LocalAddress` property, it will include IPv6 listeners as well.

Answer (score 0):

### If not using `Get-NetTCPConnection`

Here's an example of how to correctly parse `netstat`s output, similar to [Get-NetTCPConnection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/nettcpip/get-nettcpconnection?view=winserver2012r2-ps&redirectedfrom=MSDN)

[image]

### Objects are Created Automatically from a Regex's Capture Group Names

```
$RegexNetstat = @'
(?x)
    # parse output from: "netstat -a -n -o
    #   you do not need to skip or filter lines like: "| Select-Object -Skip 4"
    #   because this correctly captures records with empty States
    ^\s+
    (?<Protocol>\S+)
    \s+
    (?<LocalAddress>\S+)
    \s+
    (?<ForeignAddress>\S+)
    \s+
    (?<State>\S{0,})?
    \s+
    (?<Pid>\S+)$
'@


if (! $NetstatStdout) {
    $NetstatStdout = & netstat -a -n -o
}
# If you're on Pwsh7 you can simplify it using null-*-operators
# $NetstatStdout ??= & netstat -a -n -o

function Format-NetStat {
    param(
        # stdin
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [AllowEmptyString()]
        [AllowNull()]
        [Alias('Stdin')]
        [string]$Text
    )

    process {
        if ($Text -match $RegexNetstat) {
            $Matches.Remove(0)
            $hash = $Matches
            $hash['Process'] = Get-Process -Id $hash.Pid
            $hash['ProcessName'] = $hash['Process'].ProcessName
            $hash['LocalPort'] = $hash['LocalAddress'] -split ':' | select -last 1
            [pscustomobject]$Matches
        }
    }
}
```

### Piping Results

They are true objects, so you can pipe, filter, group, etc. as normal. (I cached Stdout for this demo, so you can compare output of the same results)

[image]

usage:

```
$Stats = $NetstatStdout | Format-NetStat
$stats | Format-Table
```

### Your Original Column Layout

```
PS> $stats | Ft -AutoSize Protocol, LocalPort, ForeignAddress, State, PID

Protocol LocalPort ForeignAddress       State       Pid
-------- --------- --------------       -----       ---
TCP      135       0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   1484
TCP      445       0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   4
TCP      808       0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   5608
TCP      5040      0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   9300
TCP      5357      0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   4
TCP      5432      0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   7480
TCP      11629     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   14400
TCP      27036     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   9196
TCP      49664     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   1116
TCP      49665     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   880
TCP      49666     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   1012
TCP      49667     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   1272
TCP      49668     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   3440
TCP      49669     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   4892
TCP      49678     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   1096
TCP      57621     0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   14400
TCP      1053      127.0.0.1:1054       ESTABLISHED 22328
TCP      1054      127.0.0.1:1053       ESTABLISHED 22328
TCP      5354      0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   5556
TCP      5354      127.0.0.1:49671      ESTABLISHED 5556
TCP      5354      127.0.0.1:49672      ESTABLISHED 5556
TCP      6463      0.0.0.0:0            LISTENING   16780
TCP      7659      127.0.0.1:7660       ESTABLISHED 18428
TCP      7660      127.0.0.1:7659       ESTABLISHED 18428
TCP      7661      127.0.0.1:7662       ESTABLISHED 4792
TCP      7662      127.0.0.1:7661       ESTABLISHED 4792
TCP      7665      127.0.0.1:7666       ESTABLISHED 1340
TCP      7666      127.0.0.1:7665       ESTABLISHED 1340
TCP      7667      127.0.0.1:7668       ESTABLISHED 11212
TCP      7668      127.0.0.1:7667       ESTABLISHED 11212
```

Originally from: [Parsing Native Apps/Invoke-Netstat](https://github.com/ninmonkey/Mini.Examples-PowerShell/blob/65faec78ad3454933cdf57e913fcd21bb26fc14c/Parsing%20Native%20Apps/Invoke-Netstat/readme.md)